# Field mapping result insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, facebook, lead

I am trying to finish the last function of a script that `sync data` added in `Facebook` lead form to `MySQL database`. I am trying to `map` `MySQL columns to Facebook` lead form fields then when `new entry` added in Facebook lead each content to be added to MySQL column as rows depending on `mapping` chosen in `script setting page`.

I have now 2 arrays

**1.** The first one `$mapfieldarray contain  key ==> value` where
 - `key` is `MySQL columns` and
 - `value` is the `Facebook fields` I map to the columns

```
  Array
         (
            [key] => phone_number_col
             [values] => phone_number

         )
     (
             [key] => full_name_col
             [values] => full_name


         )
```

**2.** and the second array is `$leadField contain name ==> value` 
 - where `name` is `Facebook field` that has value entered and 
 - `value` which `return field entry value`.

```
           Array

             ( [name] => phone_number 
             [values] => Array 
                ( 

                 [0] => <test lead: dummy data for phone_number>

             )

            ) (
            [name] => full_name
             [values] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => <test lead: dummy data for full_name>
                 )

         )
```

how to get this done ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

E.g. something like this:

```
$mapfieldarray = [
  'mysql_col_1' => 'fb_field_1',
  'mysql_col_2' => 'fb_field_2',
  'mysql_col_3' => 'fb_field_3',
];

$leadField = [
  'fb_field_1' => 'value to save',
];

$query = 'INSERT INTO table SET ';

foreach($leadField as $fb_field => $value) {
  $mysql_field_name = array_search($fb_field, $mapfieldarray);

  if(!empty($mysql_field_name)) {
    // MAKE SURE TO ESCAPE YOUR VALUES!
    // This is just an example to show how to use array_search
    $query .= "INSERT INTO table SET $mysql_field_name = $value";
  }
}
```

What array search is doing is searching the values of the first array for a match and then returning the corresponding key, which in this case is your mysql field name.

Comment: thanks a lot , but i still have one problem that it return only one result my arrays